# Number of ways to select $t$ non adjacent couples of consecutive numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

A **good couple** of the set $\{1,...,n\}$ is a couple of the type $(k,k+1)$ where $k,k+1\in \{1,...,n\}$. Two good couples $(k,k+1)$ and $(j,j+1)$ are **disjoint** iff they don't have any element in common.

> In how many ways can I select $t$ disjoint good couples of $\{1,...,n\}$?

**My attempt**

Let's suppose we have $n$ balls
$$\bullet \bullet \cdots \bullet \bullet$$
representing the numbers $\{1,...,n\}$. I just have to select the first element of each couple, so I have just to select $t$ elements properly. When I select the $i$-th ball I substitute it with a bar $|$. The rules are that there cannot be adjacent bars and the last ball cannot be selected. To create symmetry I can add an auxiliary ball at the start so that it can't be selected just like the last one
$$\star \bullet \bullet \cdots \bullet \bullet $$
Basically this should create a bijection (through stars and bars) between the number of ways to select disjoint good couples and the number of compositions of $(n+1-t)$ in $(t+1)$ positive numbers. So according to this method the answer should be

$$\binom{n-t}{t}$$

Comment: Not following your computation.  Recursively, note that either the first element is chosen or it isn't.  If it is, then you are down to choosing $t-1$ good pairs out of $n-2$.  If it isn't, then you are choosing $t$ out of $n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $n$ identical balls and $t$ boxes, each of which can hold two balls placed side by side.  Place $2$ balls in each of the $t$ boxes.  That leaves $n - 2t$ balls.  We have $n - t$ objects to arrange, $t$ boxes each containing two balls and $n - 2t$ other balls.  Choose $t$ of the $n - t$ positions for the boxes.  Now number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the balls in the $t$ boxes are the desired set of $t$ disjoint pairs of consecutive numbers.  Hence, there are $$\binom{n - t}{t}$$ ways to select $t$ disjoint pairs of consecutive numbers from the set $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: Sorry I noticed that there was a typo in my question, now my result is the same as yours. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: While you did not explicitly say so, it looks like you are counting the number of arrangements of the remaining $n - t$ numbers that are not the first numbers in a pair of consecutive numbers.  If my understanding is correct, then your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

Lay the balls in a row, and let $~(k-1) = n-2t.~$

Remove the $~(k-1)~$ balls that will not be selected.

Note that the specific $~(k-1)~$ un-selected balls completely determine the (satisfying) pairings.

Further, the removal of the $~(k-1)~$ un-selected balls create $~k~$ islands of selected balls, and you can assign the variables $~x_1, \cdots, x_k~$ to the size of the respective islands.  Note that from the constraints of the problem, $~x_1, \cdots, x_k~$ must each be an even non-negative integer. Note also that the specific values assigned to $~x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k~$ completely determine which $~(k-1)~$ balls will not be selected.

Then, you want the number of even non-negative integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n - (k-1) = 2t.$$

For $~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\},~$ let $~y_i = \dfrac{x_i}{2}.~$

Then, the problem has been reduced to computing the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = t. \tag1 $$

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

By Stars and Bars theory, the number of non-negative integer solutions to (1) above is

$$\binom{t + [k-1]}{k-1} = \binom{t + [n-2t]}{n - 2t} = \binom{n-t}{n-2t} = \binom{n-t}{t}.$$